# Disk encryption using CMK for VM via Terraform code

Tags: azure-keyvault, terraform-provider-azure

I have created the terraform script to use the CMK from Azure keyvault, however my os disk is still encrypted with PMK instead CMK, is there any other possibility to make it accessing the disk encryption using CMK by default via terraform

Tried using disk encryption set, added extensions

Answer (score 0):

> I have created the terraform script to use the CMK from Azure keyvault, however my os disk is still encrypted with PMK instead CMK, is there any other possibility to make it accessing the disk encryption using CMK by default via terraform

Here is the updated Terraform code to create `VM` with disk encryption using `CMK` by default.

```json
    provider "azurerm" {
        features {}
    }
    
    data "azurerm_client_config" "current" {}
    
    resource "azurerm_resource_group" "example" {
      name     = "encryption-resources"
      location = "West Europe"
    }
    
    resource "azurerm_key_vault" "example" {
      name                        = "encry-venkat-keyvault"
      location                    = azurerm_resource_group.example.location
      resource_group_name         = azurerm_resource_group.example.name
      tenant_id                   = data.azurerm_client_config.current.tenant_id
      sku_name                    = "premium"
      enabled_for_disk_encryption = true
      purge_protection_enabled    = true
      enable_rbac_authorization   = true
    }
    
    resource "azurerm_role_assignment" "key_vault_admin_assignment" {
      scope                = azurerm_key_vault.example.id
      role_definition_name = "Key Vault Administrator"
      principal_id         = "b70519fb-7ca5-446d-b788-a5268970efd7"
    }
    
    resource "azurerm_key_vault_key" "example" {
      name         = "encryption-demo-key"
      key_vault_id = azurerm_key_vault.example.id
      key_type     = "RSA"
      key_size     = 2048
    
      key_opts = [
       "decrypt",
        "encrypt",
        "sign",
        "unwrapKey",
        "verify",
        "wrapKey",
      ]
      
    }
    
    resource "azurerm_disk_encryption_set" "example" {
      name                = "encryptionset"
      resource_group_name = azurerm_resource_group.example.name
      location            = azurerm_resource_group.example.location
      key_vault_key_id    = azurerm_key_vault_key.example.id
    
      identity {
        type = "SystemAssigned"
      }
    }
    
    resource "azurerm_role_assignment" "example-disk" {
      scope                = azurerm_key_vault.example.id
      role_definition_name = "Key Vault Crypto Service Encryption User"
      principal_id         = azurerm_disk_encryption_set.example.identity.0.principal_id
    }
    
    resource "azurerm_virtual_network" "tfencrypt_vnet" {
      name                = "tfencrypt_vnet"
      address_space       = ["10.0.0.0/16"]
      location            = azurerm_resource_group.example.location
      resource_group_name = azurerm_resource_group.example.name
    }
    
    resource "azurerm_subnet" "tfencrypt_subnet" {
      name                 = "tfencrypt_subnet"
      resource_group_name  = azurerm_resource_group.example.name
      virtual_network_name = azurerm_virtual_network.tfencrypt_vnet.name
      address_prefixes       = ["10.0.0.0/24"]
    }
    resource "azurerm_network_interface" "tfencrypt_nic" {
      name                = "tfencrypt_nic"
      location            = azurerm_resource_group.example.location
      resource_group_name = azurerm_resource_group.example.name
    
      ip_configuration {
        name                          = "ipconfig1"
        subnet_id                     = azurerm_subnet.tfencrypt_subnet.id
        private_ip_address_allocation = "Dynamic"
      }
    }
    resource "azurerm_linux_virtual_machine" "tfencrypt_vm" {
      name                  = "tfencrypt"
      location              = azurerm_resource_group.example.location
      resource_group_name   = azurerm_resource_group.example.name
      network_interface_ids = [azurerm_network_interface.tfencrypt_nic.id]
      size               = "Standard_F2s"
      admin_username = "benhu"
      admin_password = "Password1234!"
      disable_password_authentication = false
    
      source_image_reference {
        publisher = "Canonical"
        offer     = "UbuntuServer"
        sku       = "18.04-LTS"
        version   = "latest"
      }
    
      os_disk {
        name          = "tfencrypt_osdisk"
        caching       = "ReadWrite"
        storage_account_type = "Premium_LRS"
        disk_encryption_set_id = azurerm_disk_encryption_set.example.id
      }
    }
```

After running the above terraform code, the VM has been encrypted with CMK by default.

[image]